# Prevent UIScrollView scrolling while subview is dragged

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, uipagecontrol

I have a UIButton within a UIScrollView with paging. I have implemented

> UIControlEventTouchDragInside

```
[transButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

event for that button. Some times when the button is dragged the the scroll view scrolls to next page.

How can I prevent the scrollview detecting the swipe event when the UIButton is dragged?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW36), use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`

```
[[scrollView panGestureRecognizer] requireGestureRecognizerToFail:yourSwipeGestureRecognizer];
```